# Can't stratify output in a customized way

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a script to parse few data points from an [htmlfile link](https://filebin.redpill-linpro.com/zj2qqc27va5fatm0/index.html) and write the same to a csv file according to [this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQLZ3.jpg).

I do locate the fields accordingly using the selectors I've already defined within the script, but I can't stratify the output in the right way so that I can write them later to a csv file.

location of data points:

```
Nature of association

`from 1st table`
Purpose
In cash (Previous balance)

`from 2nd table`
Donor Name
Address

`from 3rd table`
Country Name
Amount
```

Here is what I've tried (`I suppose the htmlfile link works`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file_link = 'https://filebin.redpill-linpro.com/zj2qqc27va5fatm0/index.html'

res = requests.get(file_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
nature_of_asso = soup.select_one("td:contains('Nature of association') + td").get_text(strip=True)

for purpose_tr in soup.select("table:has(> tr > td:nth-of-type(1) + td:contains('Purpose')) tr")[3:]:
    try:
        purpose = purpose_tr.select_one('td:nth-of-type(2)').get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError: purpose = ""
    try:
        in_cash = purpose_tr.select_one('td:nth-of-type(3)').get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError: in_cash = ""
    print(purpose,in_cash)

for donor_tr in soup.select("table:has(> tr > td:nth-of-type(1) + td:contains('Donor Name')) tr")[2:]:
    try:
        donor_name = donor_tr.select_one('td:nth-of-type(2)').get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError: donor_name = ""
    try:
        address = donor_tr.select_one('td:nth-of-type(3)').get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError: address = ""
    print(donor_name,address)

for country_tr in soup.select("table:has(> tr > td:nth-of-type(1) + td:contains('Country Name')) tr")[1:]:
    try:
        country = country_tr.select_one('td:nth-of-type(2)').get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError: country = ""
    try:
        amount = country_tr.select_one('td:nth-of-type(3)').get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError: amount = ""
    print(country,amount)
```

> How can I arrange output as per the image above in order to write the same to a csv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use pandas for the whole thing and clean the tables, then left join the main `DataFrame`, with most rows, on the others, using `Sl.No`.

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html('https://filebin.redpill-linpro.com/zj2qqc27va5fatm0/index.html')
df = tables[4]
df = df.iloc[2:-1, :3]
df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]
df.drop(labels = 2, axis = 0, inplace = True)

df_donor = tables[8]
df_donor = df_donor.iloc[:-2, :]
df_donor.columns = df_donor.iloc[0, :]
df_donor = df_donor.iloc[2:, :3]

df_country = tables[10]
df_country = df_country.iloc[:-1, :]
df_country.columns = df_country.iloc[0, :]
df_country = df_country.iloc[1:, :]

df.rename(columns = {'Sl.No.':'Sl.No'}, inplace = True)
df = pd.merge(df, df_donor, on = df.columns[0], how = 'left')
df = pd.merge(df, df_country, on = df.columns[0], how = 'left')
df =  df.iloc[:, 1:]
df.insert(loc = 0, column= 'Nature of association', value = '')

df_association = tables[2]
association = df_association[df_association[0].str.contains('Nature of association')].iloc[:, 1].item()

df.iloc[0,0] = association
print(df)
```

---

If you want more surety over targeting the right tables, then bring in `BeautifulSoup` and `:-soup-contains` to target the right tables:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://filebin.redpill-linpro.com/zj2qqc27va5fatm0/index.html')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

df =  pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table:-soup-contains("Sl.No.")')))[0]
df_donor = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table:-soup-contains("Donor Name")')))[0]
df_association = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table:-soup-contains("Association details")')))[0]
df_country = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('table:-soup-contains("Country Name")')))[0]

df = df.iloc[2:-1, :3]
df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]
df.drop(labels = 2, axis = 0, inplace = True)

df_donor = df_donor.iloc[:-2, :]
df_donor.columns = df_donor.iloc[0, :]
df_donor = df_donor.iloc[2:, :3]

df_country = df_country.iloc[:-1, :]
df_country.columns = df_country.iloc[0, :]
df_country = df_country.iloc[1:, :]

df.rename(columns = {'Sl.No.':'Sl.No'}, inplace = True)
df = pd.merge(df, df_donor, on = df.columns[0], how = 'left')
df = pd.merge(df, df_country, on = df.columns[0], how = 'left')
df =  df.iloc[:, 1:]
df.insert(loc = 0, column= 'Nature of association', value = '')

association = df_association[df_association[0].str.contains('Nature of association')].iloc[:, 1].item()

df.iloc[0,0] = association
print(df)
```

---

You can then handle `NaN` as required, per column, and use `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` method to write out to csv.

---

You could of course do most of this with `BeautifulSoup` alone, but you would need to retrieve the `Sl.No` so as to enable row matching for output when joining up results (given differing numbers of results for your current css selectors).

---

It is probably worth researching if dropping columns, rows is more/less efficient than subsetting.

Comment: Ah... I didn't know. No worries. Looks like you now have a good answer with csv module. In terms of :-soup-contains it is detailed here: https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:-soup-contains. The former :contains is being deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

@QHarr answer is already good, so go with it. I just show how you can slightly modify your script, "zip" the data together and write it to the CSV file:

```py
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import zip_longest

#
# I'm using your script:
#

file_link = "https://filebin.redpill-linpro.com/zj2qqc27va5fatm0/index.html"

res = requests.get(file_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
nature_of_asso = soup.select_one(
    "td:contains('Nature of association') + td"
).get_text(strip=True)

purpose_in_cash = []
for purpose_tr in soup.select(
    "table:has(> tr > td:nth-of-type(1) + td:contains('Purpose')) tr"
)[3:]:
    try:
        purpose = purpose_tr.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").get_text(
            strip=True
        )
    except AttributeError:
        purpose = ""
    try:
        in_cash = purpose_tr.select_one("td:nth-of-type(3)").get_text(
            strip=True
        )
    except AttributeError:
        in_cash = ""
    purpose_in_cash.append((purpose, in_cash))  # <--- Add the data into a list in form of tuples

donnor_address = []
for donor_tr in soup.select(
    "table:has(> tr > td:nth-of-type(1) + td:contains('Donor Name')) tr"
)[2:]:
    try:
        donor_name = donor_tr.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").get_text(
            strip=True
        )
    except AttributeError:
        donor_name = ""
    try:
        address = donor_tr.select_one("td:nth-of-type(3)").get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError:
        address = ""
    donnor_address.append((donor_name, address)) # <--- Add the data into a list in form of tuples

country_amount = []
for country_tr in soup.select(
    "table:has(> tr > td:nth-of-type(1) + td:contains('Country Name')) tr"
)[1:]:
    try:
        country = country_tr.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").get_text(
            strip=True
        )
    except AttributeError:
        country = ""
    try:
        amount = country_tr.select_one("td:nth-of-type(3)").get_text(strip=True)
    except AttributeError:
        amount = ""
    country_amount.append((country, amount)) # <--- Add the data into a list in form of tuples


# Zip it together using itertools.zip_longest

with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)

    writer.writerow(
        [
            "Nature of association",
            "Purpose",
            "In cash (Previous balance)",
            "Donor Name",
            "Address",
            "Country Name",
            "Amount",
        ]
    )

    for a, b, c, d in zip_longest(
        [nature_of_asso], purpose_in_cash, donnor_address, country_amount
    ):
        writer.writerow(
            [
                a if a else "",
                *(b if b else ("", "")),
                *(c if c else ("", "")),
                *(d if d else ("", "")),
            ]
        )
```

Saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: So, I was already on the right track. [This is how](https://pastebin.com/1mKmTF5m) I tried in the first pace but I was not sure about my attempt.

Comment: @MITHU Yes, you got it almost right :) btw. `zip_longest` is very useful.

Comment: Very nice answer

Comment: I wish I could accept both the answers I got.